# How to update an entry on table with unique column using Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unique-constraint

I have a class model like this:

```
public class Perfil
{
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaCreacion { get; set; }
        [Index(IsUnique = true)]
        public Modelo.Enumeraciones.ERoles Rol { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to update only one entry using this code: (contexto is my dbContext)

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put(int id, [FromBody]Models.Usuarios.Perfil value)
{
            if (id != value.ID) {
                return InternalServerError(new Exception("id de URL: "+id+ " no coincide con el del objeto enviado en el cuerpo: " + value.ID));
            }

            Models.Usuarios.Perfil perfil = contexto.Perfiles.SingleOrDefault(a => a.ID == id);

            if (EqualityComparer<Models.Usuarios.Perfil>.Default.Equals(perfil, default(Models.Usuarios.Perfil)))
            {
                return InternalServerError(new Exception("No existe un registro con id " + id + " en la tabla de perfiles."));
            }

            perfil.Descripcion = value.Descripcion;
            perfil.Rol = value.Rol;

            await contexto.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Ok(id);
}
```

For any reason i am getting this error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Perfils' with unique index 'IX_Rol'. The duplicate key value is (3).
```

I understand that any entry added has to have a unique rol. The problem is that i am not trying to insert!!, i want to update the rol and description properties of the entry. I am testing this with only one entry in the table and i want to update it.

I have tested many things like change the state of the entry to modified or attach the entry. Some of this tests insert a new entry in db, giving me two entries in the table. I don't understand why the entry is not being updating. I think this trouble is caused because of the Unique column Rol.

Comment: Are the Description/Rol values changed? or are you trying to update with same data again?

Comment: "I understand that any entry added has to have a unique rol. " - Not only! Updated entity has to have a unique rol too. Inique Index  is checked for the whole db table. Otherwise it will not have any sense.

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava The value incoming in the signature of the method has a new entry. I want to update perfil with the incoming value. Of course, i am changing the rol to be different to the one i have in db. In few words, i want to change the rol property from rol A to rol B

Comment: @DiegoArturo Does an equivalent update statement work directy on DB Editor?

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava I have just executed this statement: 
update [dbo].[Perfils] set [Rol]=0 
this replaces from rol = 3 to rol = 0 and works perfectly.

Comment: I have found something. When i make a request to the Put method from postman, it works as expected. The record in db is updated and there is not duplicate records. The problem seems to be related with a .Test proyect that instanciate my controller to make the request. In the test i perform a Post to create the first record, then it executes a GetId to get that record from db. Finally it modifies the record obtined with a new Rol and executes the Put. Do that makes a double insert. Observing the two record it actually updates the first record.

Comment: The error indicates that there is a unique constraint on the Rol field meaning only one Prefil row in the database can exist for any Rol value. (Sounds like an odd constraint to have on a non-key value that is editable) If this is as-expected and you are certain there should only be one Prefil record in the table that you are trying to update then I would double-check the connection string that your app is using at runtime (`context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;`) to verify the app is pointing at the database you are checking against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discovered what was happend. I should have told in the question that this method were being executed from a unit test project. I was doing the execution in the following order:

- Post
- Get
- Update
- Delete

Besides, the whole operation was within a [TestMethod]. It seems that use the same object posted for putting makes the entity thinks that two objects are attached to it. That's why some of the tests give me as result two insertions. The solution was to split Post, Get, Update and Delete into a single [TestMethod] for each one.